# MySQL: Select range close to name

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this is possible, so I'm currently just selecting all from the group, putting the results into an array, then slicing it. But here's an example table:

```
id - groupid - item
1 - 1 - red
2 - 1 - blue
3 - 1 - green
4 - 2 - strawberries
5 - 2 - grapes
6 - 2 - oranges
7 - 1 - purple
8 - 1 - black
9 - 2 - apples
```

etc..

How would I be able to get 3 results from a group based on an item? Like the item itself, then 1 before, 1 after, in alphabetical order.

So:

Item is grapes:

```
9 - apples
5 - grapes
6 - oranges
```

Item is green:

```
2 - blue
3 - green
7 - purple
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
select t.*, max(tr.item) prevItem, min(tl.item) nextItem
from t 
left join t tl on t.groupid = tl.groupid and t.item < tl.item
left join t tr on t.groupid = tr.groupid and t.item > tr.item
group by t.id, t.groupid, t.item
order by t.groupid, t.item;
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d34d76/1)

Answer (score 0):

this is as far as I can get

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t1.*
   FROM things t1
   INNER JOIN things t2 ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid
   WHERE t2.item = 'green' and t1.item < 'green'
   ORDER BY t1.item DESC
   LIMIT 1
) A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM things B WHERE item = 'green'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t1.*
   FROM things t1
   INNER JOIN things t2 ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid
   WHERE t2.item = 'green' and t1.item > 'green'
   ORDER BY t1.item
   LIMIT 1
) C
```

that way, you need to change the parameter in every sub-query

here is an example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oCYdeiak1RjKUvNvZM5Eq5/0